# Unable to get NSMutableArray value in function

Tags: objective-c, nsmutablearray

I am getting the nsMutaryOfDataObject value in the reload function but not getting it in in `- (int)numberOfRowsInTableView:(NSTableView *)pTableViewObj`... In this function mutablearray is getting nil.

I'm unable to understand why. How can this happen?

Comment: is it must to add init method???i have no need to initialize any variable....i am initializing my mutablearray in another class..

Answer (score 0):

you have to retain the array, the other class that creates it probably releases it.

```
- (void) setMutableArray:(NSMutableArray *)arr
{
  [instanceVar release];
  instanceVar = nil;
  instanceVar = [arr retain];
}
```

You should be somewhat more clear with your code though, maybe add some logging calls when you "create" or set the array.